# Linking active directory user with SQL SERVER login account

Tags: powershell

Good day. Am working in an environment that requires a security approach for checking users account (users in the active directory are changing data in the SQL SERVER).

I want to link/tie the users of an active directory to the SQL server account login account.

Am working with Powershell,  i type `Get-ADUser -filter *`, it gives me the list of all listed users. If i log into my SQL SERVER with "winnie", how do i link/tie the active directory user with the sql server user called  ""winnie"

Answer (score 1):

You should never give users access to a database by single Windows User or by SQL User. The reason for this is because of the security later on. It will be better to manage and audit a group compared to giving out single users. If you have to restore that database to a new system. It will provide better security between a Production system and a Test system.

The only user who should have access to a database is the SA account. The others should be controlled by Security Groups.

How do you do this:
In SQL Server Management Studio, go to Object Explorer > (your server) > Security > Logins and right-click New Login:

[image: New Login]

Then in the dialog box that pops up, pick the types of objects you want to see (Groups is disabled by default - check it!) and pick the location where you want to look for your objects (e.g. use Entire Directory) and then find your AD group.

[image: Add Group]

Any member of that AD group can now login to SQL Server and use your database.

[image: Group Security]

Add the Read or Write permissions to the Security Group of choice. Limiting security issues it the future.

Best Practice:
Create Security Groups
Security Group naming convention exmaples:
SG_DBNAME_READ
SG_DBNAME_WRITE
SG_DBSERVER_ADMIN